# Flutter: How can I disable workspace trust in VS Code 1.57 keep crashing flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, mobile

How can I disable workspace trust in VS Code 1.57 keep crashing flutter app.
I keep getting error when running flutter

Comment: workspace trust has nothing to do with crashing your app, if you can debug/run your app you trust this workspace, their is a bug in your code

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `security.workspace.trust.enabled` to `false` (as per the documentation of VS Code).
See this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust#_can-i-disable-the-workspace-trust-feature) for more information.